# Updating BigQuery dataset access from C#

Tags: c#, google-bigquery, dataset, roles, access-rights

I am working with BigQuery. I create a DataSet and I want to define access rights with C# language. 
It's not clear to me how to do it. 
In  GOOGLE web page https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls is explained how to do it with some example for Java and Pyton (see below), but no example is provided for c#.

```
example in pyton:
dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_id)  # Make an API request.

entry = bigquery.AccessEntry(
    role="READER",
    entity_type="userByEmail",
    entity_id="sample.bigquery.dev@gmail.com",
)

entries = list(dataset.access_entries)
entries.append(entry)
dataset.access_entries = entries

dataset = client.update_dataset(dataset, ["access_entries"])  # Make an API request.

full_dataset_id = "{}.{}".format(dataset.project, dataset.dataset_id)
```

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably best to use the `BigQueryDataset.Patch` method, from the `Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2` package:

```cs
// Fetch the existing dataset
var client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);
var dataset = client.GetDataset(datasetId);

var accessList = dataset.Resource.Access ?? new List<AccessData>();
accessList.Add(new AccessData
{
    Role = "Reader",
    UserByEmail = "sample.bigquery.dev@gmail.com"
});
var patchedResource = new Dataset { Access = accessList };

// Push the changes back up to BigQuery
dataset.Patch(patchedResource, matchETag: true);
```

As an alternative, you can use `Update` to update the replace the dataset resource completely:

```cs
// Fetch the existing dataset
var client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);
var dataset = client.GetDataset(datasetId);

// Modify it in memory
var resource = dataset.Resource;
if (resource.Access is null)
{
    // If there's no access list yet, create one.
    resource.Access = new List<AccessData>();
}
var newAccess = new AccessData
{
    Role = "Reader",
    UserByEmail = "sample.bigquery.dev@gmail.com"
};
resource.Access.Add(newAccess);

// Push the changes back up to BigQuery
dataset.Update();
```

Comment: Hello Jon Skeet,
Thank you very much for your advice. I think your solution is good. 
Unfurtunatelly I didn't read it before, but I have implemented something very similar and it worked.
The only difference is that I use the Patch function insead of Update.
I will publish my method.

Comment: @ClementeMadrassi: Note the first of my examples uses Patch too.

Comment: @Debasish22: Please don't use comments on one post to get attention to a different one. I'll have a look now, but it's really not an appropriate use of comments.

Comment: @JonSkeet sure . Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

At the and I managed to make it work.
I used the same solution suggested by Jon Skeet, using the Patch method.
I attach my code here by.

public static bool GrantDatasetAccess(string dataSetId, bool online, string role, string email,
            string bigQueryJsonPath, string bigQueryScope, string projectId, clsLog log)
        {

```
        try
        {
            BigQueryClient client = GetBigQueryClient(online, bigQueryJsonPath, bigQueryScope, projectId);
            BigQueryDataset dataset = GetDataSet(online, dataSetId, bigQueryJsonPath, bigQueryScope, projectId, log);

            List<AccessData> accessList = new List<AccessData>();
            var accessData = new AccessData()
            {
                Role = role,
                GroupByEmail = null,
                UserByEmail = email,
                SpecialGroup = null,
                IamMember = null,
                Domain = null,
                View = null

            };
            accessList.Add(accessData);
            dataset.Resource.Access = accessList;
            dataset.Patch(dataset.Resource, true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.ManageError("Error GetDataSet: {0}\nError: {1}", dataSetId, string.Concat(e.Message, "\n", e.StackTrace));
        }
        return true;
    }
```